# How to make Google Docs automatically correct misspellings

Tags: google-docs

I would like Google Docs to automatically correct misspellings, not underline them for me to manually correct. Is this possible?

"Automatically correct spelling" is already selected.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Docs cannot automatically correct miss-spellings, only underline them. You could try to search for an add-on that will do that. Just click the Add-Ons button in the menu.